# When should files be excluded from single minified JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, cdn

I've been reading about the benefits of limiting the number of requests to the server, and stringing all JS (and CSS) files into a single file.

I've also been reading about the benefits of using files hosted by a CDN.

Is it best to use individual requests for all possible files hosted by a CDN and only combine files which are not hosted by a CDN into a single file, or not use the CDF hosted files and instead combine all files into a single file?

EDIT.  I recognize "best" might be considered subjective by some (however, I don't feel it is).  If you feel so, please provide the pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: CDNs are great. But never forget that you're making yourself vulnerable by using an external service. There are still people caring for privacy and such stupid things. I feel like too many people don't consider this an issue.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s  Also, the rare chance that the CDN is down.  It seems like fallback is fairly straightforward for JS, but CSS is a bit more tricky.  Looks like fallback and yepnope are two libraries that help to overcome. Not directly related to my question, but would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general both two solutions can be good. The trick stay in choose the correct operation for every situation.
For example if you have 5 js files of 10KB each one, minify all to one 50KB make site faster. But if you have 5 files of 500kb each one, minify all to one 2.5MB will block all site until js file is loaded, is more fast load separately in this case.

CDN always improve performance, using CDN + minify improve more.

Minify sure improve performance if you have many  http requests( > 15), this is a common situation in CMS based website like Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks Federico.  Sounds like you recommend doing my first option.